# How do I disable werfault.exe for my app?

Tags: windows, crash

I have to run this program millions of times.  It's not the most stable beast, and it crashes around 5% of the time.  When this happens, I don't want a popup, or WerFault to take 30 sec to take a dump, or anything - I just want it to silently and immediately disappear, and I'll figure out it crashed from the process exit code.

I already have Windows Error Reporting Service disabled, and my AEDebug key deleted.  However, werfault is still trying to take a dump on crash.  Help?

Answer (score 4):

That can be annoying... especially if you're doing a lot of code-debug-compile-deploy-test iterations.

It looks like there are a couple of registry entries here that help control the behavior:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638(VS.85).aspx

Here's some information on how to exclude your particular application from error reporting, without completely disabling error reporting:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513617(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Keep in mind that some of this can be done through built-in GUIs instead of prorammatically.

Comment: Another way should be adding an <exe-name>.exe dword in the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\ExcludedApplications` registry key. Also make sure there aren't corresponding entries in *DebugApplications* I guess.